# Find missing times from generated array list python

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, typeerror

I'm trying to find missing times in a list that is generated by gathering data from a MySQL database. This means the test_list values will always be different each time the function runs.

My code:

```
def get_time_slotes():
    test_list = sorted([u'08:00', u'12:00', u'13:00', u'09:00', u'10:00', u'17:00'])

    res = list(set(range(max(test_list) + 1)) - set(test_list)) 
    print("The list of missing elements : " + str(res))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    get_time_slotes()
```

But I'm receiving this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/liesching/Documents/test.py", line 41, in <module>
    get_time_slotes()
  File "/Users/liesching/Documents/test.py", line 36, in get_time_slotes
    res = list(set(range(max(test_list) + 1)) - set(test_list)) 
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, int found
```

I'm working in Python 2.7 if that makes any difference. It is a constraint as i'm building on top of an already existing application

Comment: Why are you using python 2.7? Is this a constraint?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately... building it ontop of an existing system that was built in 2.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used datetime to solve your problem. First I encoded each element in utf-8.

The code it's not clean, but it works!!

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, time

def get_time_slotes():

    list_of_times = [u'08:00', u'12:00', u'13:00', u'09:00', u'10:00', u'17:00']
    test_list = sorted(datetime.strptime(x.encode('utf-8'),'%H:%M').time() for x in list_of_times)
    
    res = [x.strftime("%H:%M") for x in sorted(set(time(x,0,0,0) for x in range(max(test_list).hour)) - set(test_list))]

    print("The list of missing elements : " + str(res))
```

output:

```
The list of missing elements : ['00:00', '01:00', '02:00', '03:00', '04:00', '05:00', '06:00', '07:00', '11:00', '14:00', '15:00', '16:00']
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `max(test_list)` returns `u'17:00'` so you need to convert that to 17 as range takes an int. Then you also need to do that for each item in `set(test_list)` and then afterwards covert the numbers back to times. example:

```
def get_hour(time):
  """ u'08:00' -> 8 """
  return int(time.split(":")[0])

def get_time(hour):
  """ 8 -> u'08:00' """
  return (u'%s:00' % hour).zfill(5)
   
def get_time_slotes():
    test_list = sorted([u'08:00', u'12:00', u'13:00', u'09:00', u'10:00', u'17:00'])

    res = map(get_time, list(set(range(get_hour(max(test_list)) + 1)) - set(map(get_hour, test_list))))
    print("The list of missing elements : " + str(res))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    get_time_slotes()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here concatenating unicode to int:

`u'17:00' + 1`

Maybe if you parse the time, it will be easier task, something like:

```
from datetime import datetime

def get_time_slotes():
    test_list = [u'08:00', u'12:00', u'13:00', u'09:00', u'10:00', u'17:00']
    test_list = [datetime.strptime(t, '%H:%M').hour for t in test_list]

    res = set(range(max(test_list) + 1)) - set(test_list)
    print("The list of missing elements : " + str(res))

get_time_slotes()
```

Output:

```
The list of missing elements : {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 11, 14, 15, 16}
```